# Given two Input values How can I calculate... this.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

So given two variable `A` and `B` which are both whole positive numbers I want to calculate the chance that a random real number chosen from the range spanning from `0.4*A` to `A` is greater than a random real number chosen from the range spanning from `0.4*B` to `B`. I know how to calculate this using [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/304444/given-two-different-ranges-probability-of-a-number-in-one-range-being-greater-t?rq=1) questions answer but I need to be able to calculate it using a formula. (If its useful I am planning on using this in a google sheet and so any function in standard google sheets is welcome)

Comment: "*a random number chosen...*"  A random real number chosen?  A random whole number chosen?  You link a highly relevant question with an already well written answer.  What is preventing you from being able to generalize the formula from what was explained in the linked answer?

Comment: Specified Real Numbers. the issue I'm getting tripped up on with the answer to the other question is basically turning it into an equation... I can visualise the points and have made multiple diagrams but I cant seem to take it to that next step.

Comment: Without loss of generality, let $A<B$.  Let $X$ be the random variable picked from the range $0.4A,A$ and let $Y$ be the random variable picked from $0.4B,B$.  If $X$ and $Y$ both happen to be in the range from $0.4B,A$ then since you are dealing with real numbers its an equal chance for $X$ to be bigger than $Y$.  If $X$ lies in the range $0.4A,0.4B$ then its automatic that $X<Y$.  If $Y$ lies in the range $A,B$ then its automatic that $X<Y$.  (*Note that it is possible for $X$ to be in $0.4A,0.4B$ and $Y$ to be in $A,B$ simultaneously, adjust calculations as necessary*).  Conclude.

Comment: $Pr(X<Y) = Pr(0.4A\leq X<0.4B)+Pr(A\leq Y<B)-Pr(0.4A\leq X<0.4B,A\leq Y<B) + \frac{1}{2}Pr(0.4B\leq X<A,0.4B\leq Y<A)$.  Simplify further as you like

Comment: **A > B** can be true. will that be an issue for that equation?

Comment: If $A>B$ is true instead of $A<B$... then just replace all occurrences of $A$ with $B$ and vice versa in what the result would have been.  If it causes you that much frustration, then use instead $\min(A,B)$ and $\max(A,B)$ in the formula instead and avoid the issue altogether.  Writing it with that though makes it hard to read

Comment: Just to be certain. I'm still trying to get the probability of the value from .4A,A  < value from .4B,B whilst A > B

Comment: because if I'm not mistaken switching all of them around would get you A < B wouldnt it?

Answer (score 0):

Draw a rectangle with sides $A$ and $B$ parallel to the $x$ and $y$ axes. Shade the region where your inequality holds. Calculate its area, divide by $AB$ to get the probability you want.

You should be able to do that calculation in a spreadsheet.

Comment: A slightly different nuance in the event that the OP is specifically referring to selecting whole numbers only.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes, but the question says $A$ and $B$ are integers although the chosen point is real.

Comment: After the edit it clarified that point.  Before the edit it was still ambiguous and the linked question which was supposedly a duplicate just without fully generalized results was explicitly only picking whole numbers in the corresponding ranges.

Comment: The question is "How can I calculate this" so saying to "Calculate it" doesn't really help. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: You're welcome. I thought that reducing the question to calculating the areas of some rectangles would be enough for you to take pleasure in finishing the problem yourself. Or you can just plug @JMoravitz 's answer into your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Summarizing comments above...

Without loss of generality, let $A<B$.

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the first number which was chosen uniformly at random from the reals within the range $[0.4A,A]$.

Let $Y$ be the random variable denoting the first number which was chosen uniformly at random from the reals within the range $[0.4B,B]$.

We note that if $X$ and $Y$ are both within the intersections of the ranges, $[0.4B,A]$, then there is equal chance for $X$ to be greater than $Y$ as for $X$ to be less than $Y$.  (*It is impossible [occurs with zero probability] for $X$ to be equal to $Y$ since we are selecting real numbers uniformly at random.  If selecting integers instead, this isn't true*).  Further, we note that if $X$ were in the range $[0.4A,0.4B]$, i.e. if $X$ were smaller than the smallest possible value for $Y$ then clearly $X<Y$ is true.  Finally we note the analogous situation if $Y$ were larger than the largest possible value of $X$, if $Y$ were in the range $[A,B]$.  Note that it is possible for both of these last two situations to be true simultaneously which we need to take into account with inclusion-exclusion when performing the calculations.

So, we have:

$$\Pr(X<Y) = \Pr(0.4A<X<0.4B) + \Pr(A<Y<B)-\Pr(0.4A<X<0.4B,A<Y<B) + \frac{1}{2}\Pr(0.4B<X<A,0.4B<Y<A)$$

Now... let's look at each of these individual probabilities more closely.  $\Pr(0.4A<X<0.4B)$ for instance.  The range of values that $X$ can be pulled from is of measure (*length*) $0.6A$ and the range of values of $X$ which fall into this event is of measure $0.4B-0.4A$, so the probability here is $\dfrac{0.4B-0.4A}{0.6A}$ or if you prefer simplified some, $\dfrac{2}{3}\dfrac{(B-A)}{A}$.

Similarly you can replace the rest, and intersections of events can be split apart since we are assuming the selections of these values were done independently.

You get then:

$$Pr(X<Y) = \frac{0.4B-0.4A}{0.6A} + \frac{B-A}{0.6B}-\frac{0.4(B-A)^2}{0.36AB}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{(A-0.4B)^2}{0.36AB}$$

$$=\dfrac{38AB-25A^2-4B^2}{18AB}$$

---

Now... you complain in the comments that $A>B$ is possible as well.  What I wrote above assumed "*[without loss of generality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Without_loss_of_generality)*" that $A<B$.  The formula for $A>B$ is almost identical.  I'll reword it anyways...

The probability that the variable picked from the smaller range winds up smaller than the variable picked from the other range will be $\dfrac{38AB-25\min(A,B)^2-4\max(A,B)^2}{18AB}$.  The probability that the variable picked came from the larger will simply be $1$ minus the probability it came from the smaller range.

---

Note, as alluded to earlier the linked question dealt with only picking whole numbers from the respective ranges.  The problem becomes different in that case since equalities are possible and occur with positive probability.  The same general idea will work for that scenario as well, you'll just need to use counting measures rather than length measures and you'll need to correctly take into account the points along the diagonal.